# How to fit my table dimensions?

Tags: tables

My problem is with the  third column of my table. It is very big and I can't fit it width. It takes the place of other things in my document. 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c|l|X@{}}
  \toprule
  Security Level & Security Mode & Protection \\
  \midrule
  0 & No Security     & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity is not validated   \\\hline 
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC \\\hline   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using 64-bit MIC   \\\hline   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using 128-bit MIC  \\\hline   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity is not validated       \\\hline   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC     \\\hline   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Data is nencrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 64-bit MIC     \\\hline   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 128-bit MIC    \\\hline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\label{tab:tab1} {Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard. \cite{19}}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a complete MWE from your code including the document class and packages needed to reproduce your result.

Comment: To fit in a single column, use `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth`.  If it won't fit, use table* instead of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1) Do not use vertical lines and reduce horizontal lines as far as possible.

2) `tabulary` could be a better option that `tabularx` to fit a table with columns of different width and alignments with line breaks.

3) Redesign is the most important point to have smaller, clearer and more beautiful tables. Unfortunately there are not packages to redesign tables for you, and is a content/context dependent and very subjective task. So, regardless if you like the proposed redesign or not in this case, believe me: simplify means  improve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{CLCL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Security} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data protection} \\\cmidrule(rl){1-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-4}
Level & \hfil Mode & Encryption & \hfil Authenticity\\
%\midrule
\cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
  0 & No Security     & No  &  Not validated   \\
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & No  &  32-bit MIC \\   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & No  &  64-bit MIC   \\   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & No  &  128-bit MIC  \\   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Yes &  Not validated       \\   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Yes &  32-bit MIC     \\   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Yes &  64-bit MIC     \\   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Yes &  128-bit MIC    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{\label{tab:tab1} {Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard. \cite{19}}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 0):

As I said recently in answer to another table-related question: be terse.  You already don't use full sentences, so there's nothing wrong with `Data not encrypted \newline authenticity uses 32-bit MIC` etc.

You can also make the first column much narrower by using another row either for the common part of the column headings (as I've done here) or by having `Security \newline Level & Security \newline Mode & Protection` for your header row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c l X@{}}

  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Security}\\
   Level &  Mode & Protection \\
  \midrule
  0 & No Security     & Data not encrypted \newline Authenticity not validated   \\\hline 
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & Data not encrypted \newline Authenticity uses 32-bit MIC \\\hline   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & Data not encrypted \newline Authenticity using 64-bit MIC   \\\hline   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & Data not encrypted \newline Authenticity using 128-bit MIC  \\\hline   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Data encrypted \newline Authenticity not validated       \\\hline   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Data encrypted \newline Authenticity uses 32-bit MIC     \\\hline   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Data encrypted \newline Authenticity uses 64-bit MIC     \\\hline   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Data encrypted \newline Authenticity uses 128-bit MIC    \\\hline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\label{tab:tab1} {Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard. \cite{19}}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note a couple of other things:

- If you're going to use `booktabs`, read the manual and lose the vertical lines.  If you insist on vertical lines, don't use `booktabs` for the horizontal rules.
- Your `\label{tab:tab1}` defeats the object of using cross-references properly.  Be semantic, that way when you insert an earlier table you won't get confused (example: `\label{tab:SecurityModes}`).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but my is with third column.  it does not take the textwidth. I have an article with two columns, so my table take space for the fist column to the second column.

Comment: That should have been in your question and your MWE. As it is you posted a single column question with a request to make it narrower.

Comment: I am so sorry really, I updated my question.